# cursor syntax to fetch and drop tables in the db

Tags: oracle, performance, index, plsql

I have a list of tables from a select query which gives me at least 50 tables daily .
Need to drop them as they are temporary. I need a cursor to fetch and drop each one of them in a loop.
I am using oracle Db.

Comment: What have you tried?  Are you using dynamic SQL, for example?  `execute immediate` or `dbms_sql`? Are you getting an error?  If so, what error?  And that's before questioning the system design that leads you to want to do this in the first place.  You shouldn't be creating and dropping 50 tables a day.  Maybe you want to create 50 temporary tables once.  Maybe you should be using collections rather than tables in your code.

Comment: i said 50 tables for example. the sytem is a campaign application and these tables are intermediate tables which are stale after the Purpose is served.

Comment: The point stands.  Creating and dropping tables regularly in a production system is not a good design whether 1 or 100.  Intermediate tables should probably be created once as temporary tables or should be local collections.

Answer (score 1):

OK then, you were already told that what you're doing isn't the best idea. However, you might have your reasons, asked a question and here's one option. See if it helps.

In my database, Scott's sample schema is used as a *playground* and I frequently create/drop tables there. I'll keep `EMP` and `DEPT`, while other tables can be dropped (I don't need them anyway). `tab_to_drop` contains list of those tables (that's your "50 tables").

```
SQL> create table tab_to_drop as
  2    select table_name
  3    from user_tab_columns
  4    where table_name not in ('EMP', 'DEPT');

Table created.
```

PL/SQL block that loops through that table and tries to drop each of those tables. Sometimes it succeeds, sometimes not - usually when there's a foreign key constraint involved. True - you can make the script way smarter and drop constraints first and tables next, or re-run this code.

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> begin
  2    for cur_r in (select tname from tab_to_drop) loop
  3      begin
  4        execute immediate 'drop table ' || cur_r.tname;
  5        dbms_output.put_line(cur_r.tname ||' dropped');
  6      exception
  7        when others then
  8          dbms_output.put_line(cur_r.tname ||' not dropped because of ' || sqlerrm);
  9      end;
 10    end loop;
 11  end;
 12  /
ANAGRAFICA dropped
COURSE dropped
<snip>
ORDERS dropped
OWNER not dropped because of ORA-02449: unique/primary keys in table referenced by foreign keys
PIECE_OF_ART dropped
<snip>
XYZ dropped

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```